# How to make an editable Angular table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create an editable table and it's not working and I can't figure out why.

I've done some research and I understand that there are at least three options.

1. Using **FormArray** and **ngIf** on the input field
2. Using **FormGroup** and **Dynamic Component**
3. Using `<input [formControl]="row.validator.controls['fieldName']">` like in this example [angular4-material-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-material-table)

If I try to use **angular4-material-table** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tj9f6y) locally I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSrQK.jpg). Also in this example, owner of the code is using a **Template Driven** approach and I don't know how to convert to a **Reactive** approach. I tried to make my own table using first or second option without any result.

Now my code is inspired by the third option.

Here is the code - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7zhxw-v7olwa?file=app/table-basic-example.ts) (with [*@bryan60*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4855306/bryan60) adjustment)

Comment: Your stackblitz isn't working; check the console. If you're not going to include code in your post, the stackblitz should at least work. You're not even including the package you reference in this post in the stackblitz.

Comment: I know my example is not working, but that is the problem, I don't know how to fix it. I tried to create an example that was working, with 0 functionalities and I got negative rating. My actual code is not using angular4-material-table package it's just inspired from there.

Comment: You have some very basic programming/script errors. You should have a look at the console output and resolve them.

Comment: I will try to fix the error, but even if I can get rid of it the problem will be the same and the question will be the same: "How to create an editable angular table?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your input fields editable or non-editable, bind the `readonly` property to the row's `editable` value:

```
<input [readonly]="!row.editable">
```

And also update that property when you click the edit, save, and cancel buttons.

Your data is set up rather oddly. Your rows have `currentData` and `originalData` but they both point to the same object so if you change one you are changing the other. Also, your input fields store their values in their form controls, but your form controls are initialized using the data *values* not the data object that is used for currentData and originalData. So in order to push changes to the data, or reset data when you cancel an edit, you need to explicitly manage those operations:

```
confirmEditCreate(row) {
  row.editable = false;
  // save form control values to data object
  Object.keys(row.validator.controls).forEach(item => {
    row.currentData[item] = row.validator.controls[item].value;
  });
}

startEdit(row) {
  row.editable = true;
}

cancelOrDelete(row, i) {
  if (row.editable) {
    row.editable = false;
    // cancel - reset form control values to data object
    Object.keys(row.validator.controls).forEach(item => {
      row.validator.controls[item].patchValue(row.currentData[item]);
    });
  }
  else {
    // delete
    this.deleteRow(i);
  }
}
```

This is just a start at making an "editable" table - you still need to validate changes and display errors when necessary. And you probably should confirm delete actions.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7zhxw-aadgzr?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)

Comment: What do you mean by should confirm delete actions? What do you suggest for validation, more exactly what is the best practice, with form group, form builder, form array, form control? And I know that original data and current data are pointing to the same object but from my understanding original data is before update and current data is after update.

Comment: "confirm delete" === ask the user if they're sure. It's your application so you have to decide what validation is required. If you aren't sure how to start, do some reading on forms design and validation. You need to make changes if you want to keep originalData and currentData separate because your design does not work that way - that was my point - **they both share the same single object**.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with how you're declaring your form groups, you need to set a value as the first argument to a form control, and you need a new form group for every row, i made these edits:

```
const editForm = (e) => new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(e.firstName,Validators.required),
  lastName: new FormControl(e.lastName,Validators.required),
  username: new FormControl(e.username,Validators.required),
  email: new FormControl(e.email,Validators.required),
});
this.ELEMENT_DATA_FROM_BACK.forEach(element => {
  this.ELEMENT_DATA.push({currentData: element, 
                          originalData: element, 
                          editable: false, 
                          validator: editForm(element)});
});
```

and it works now:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7zhxw-swgry8?file=app/table-basic-example.ts

Comment: It's pretty close of the functionality that I am looking for but there are still some problems. I edited a bit your solution, more exactly I modified *ngIf on lines 65 and 68 in html to display the right button which was in the beginning my mistake and the code looks like this: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7zhxw-v7olwa?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)

Comment: When I click the edit button it has to change the row to an editable state from which I can see your solution does. But it also makes all table editable and it should make only one row. After you click the edit button it has to change to approve button. After you finish editing the row you have to press approve button and it has to change back to edit button. And in the end all updated data have to be stored into an array.

Comment: in the stackblitz you provided, every row was always an input... there is no switching between editable and non editable.  you need to add some logic to make it switch from input to basic display.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if you look to my main question I said that I figure out three ways to do this logic, I tried to implement all of them but it didn't work so I thought to ask here for some help.

If you look to this example - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tj9f6y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-list.component.html) which is also provided in main question you will see that the code owner has every row always as input.